# Searching files from root directory on mac - Java

Tags: java, directory, root

I have a file on my Desktop I have to find

If I insert the following code:

```
            f = new RandomAccessFile("\Desktop/greg.txt", "r");
```

I get an error on the `\`

But this is how I access the root directory. Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: In terminal it uses  ` \ `  Using `/` I still get an error `no such file or directory greg.txt `

Comment: Backslashes need to be doubled in Java string literals; here you try and insert an escape sequence which is `\D`, which is illegal in Java. So that would be `"\\Desktop"`, but even then I seriously doubt that this will work.

Comment: @ fge This doesn't create any errors but is still not finding my file.

Comment: But anyway, what do you call root? The root directory in Unix systems is /, this is very different from your home directory.

Comment: I must be making a mistake. How would I got to Home instead of Root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long since i have used a mac, but im thinking along the lines to try and change your path to

/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop/greg.txt

Or something like

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
String path = "/Users/" + username + "/Desktop/greg.txt";
```

And pass the path.

Since its OS X you can also do
~/Desktop grep.txt

in the path, where ~/ equals the users home directory.

Comment: There is also `user.home` as a property.

Comment: Type system is not applicable for argument String ?